# MySQL Select rows with same value and output to HTML css/table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would really appreciate your help on this:

```
Item_ID Buy_User    Buy_Date    Buy_Qty 
00001       Adam        01/02/2013  1
00003       John        01/01/2013  2
00004       Peter       02/01/2013  1
00001       Nial        01/01/2013  1
```

Above is an example of my table. What I need is to sql query the Item_ID column, and display each Item_ID only once - but display each of the user's who have bought that product.

I need the query to be outputted in HTML/css.

For example my html page may look like:

> Item 1: Adam bought 1. Nial bought 1.
>
> *Item 2:  (would be hidden as no purchases).*
>
> Item 3: John bought 2.
>
> Item 4: Peter bought 1.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this, I've been googling around and found multiple mentions of sub selects, but i'm not sure how i'd get it to display each row?

Help?!

Many thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "John bought 2" for Item 3?

Comment: Sorry, you're right Nitram - it should be "John bought 2". My miss-type there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  It uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to group the rows and `CONCAT` to build the strings:

```
SELECT Item_Id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Buy_User,' bought ',Buy_Qty) SEPARATOR ', ') ITEMS
FROM Items
GROUP BY Item_Id
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7e7e/6).

And here are the results:

```
ITEM_ID   ITEMS
00001     Adam bought 1, Nial bought 1
00003     John bought 2
00004     Peter bought 1
```

Comment: That is brilliant! How would I then get each row to output within the HTML table, but stay under it's respective header?

Comment: @FrailMonkey -- not sure I can help with that -- not a big php user :)  Should be lots of tutorials out there on php and mysql with prepared statements and mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  Best of luck!